# What is the difference between implicit and explicit StringBuilder.ToString() method calls?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, tostring, stringbuilder, implicit-conversion

I just wrote a small Unit Test in which I used a `StringBuilder()`.

```
var stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
stringBuilder.Append("Foo");

Assert.AreEqual(stringBuilder, "Foo");
```

This Test will fail.

```
Expected: <Foo>
But was:  "Foo"
```

But if I change the Assert to

```
Assert.AreEqual(stringBuilder.ToString(), "Foo");
```

the test will pass.

So, what is the difference between the implicit call and the explicit call of the `ToString()` method? Or/And what are these Brackets (`<>`) standing for?

Comment: There is no implicit call to ToString?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In your first example, you are testing if your `StringBuilder` *instance* is equal to the string, which will fail.

In your second one, you are testing if the result of the call to `ToString()` (which is a string) is equal to the other string.

---

The bracktes (<>) are NUnits way to indicate that it got an non-string object, but to display the message, NUnit calls `ToString()` on that object.

```
Expected: <Foo> But was: "Foo"
```

So `<Foo>` is an object that returns `Foo` on a call to `ToString()`, whereas `"Foo"` is just a `String` *Foo*.

MSTest would show you a different message, which would be more clear:

```
Expected:<Foo (System.Text.StringBuilder)>. Actual:<Foo (System.String)>.
```

Answer (score 0):

*In the first version there is no implicit call to ToString*
This only happens in methods like Console.WriteLine.

So what actually happens is that you are equating a stringbuilder object to a string object. Even the types do not match :-)

Comment: I see. Thought this implicit call will be made each time, because it works on methods like WriteLine or String.Format("foo {0} bar", sb). But as I refelect its just the Object.ToString() call that does the trick.. (And AreEqual doesn't do so)